# Can't connect to eduroam with iwd

Tags: networking, arch-linux, eduroam, iwd

I'm trying to connect to eduroam with `iwd`, but when I type

```
station wlan0 connect eduroam
```

the only thing I get is "Not configured". The config file I created at `/var/lib/iwd/eduroam.8021x` looks like this:

```
[Security]
EAP-Method=PEAP
EAP-Identity=wlan@win.tu-berlin.de
EAP-PEAP-CACert=/home/XXXX/eduroam.pem
EAP-PEAP-ServerDomainMask=*.tubit.tu-berlin.de
EAP-PEAP-Phase2-Method=MSCHAPV2
EAP-PEAP-Phase2-Identity=XXXX@win.tu-berlin.de
EAP-PEAP-Phase2-Password=XXXX

[Settings]
AutoConnect=true
```

`iwd` works fine with every other network and eduroam shows up in the known-networks list, so I don't really get where the error message comes from. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, iwd.service is unable to load `EAP-PEAP-CACert=/home/XXXX/eduroam.pem`

from the `/home` directory as it has `ProtectHome=yes` set.

Try moving the certificate into a location readable by iwd.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I moved the certificate file to the config directory and it works just fine now.